# PDF Digital Signature

Tags: certificates, digital-signature

I got free certificate from [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/free-email-certificate.php) and installed on my Windows. Now I'm trying to sign PDF document using this certificate, but get message: "signature validity is unknown":

[image]

Why is this? How I can validate my signature?

PS. Adove Reader XI Version 11.0.07

Comment: (please include the name/version of the PDF reader as well) That's a mere guess but your PDF reader probably doesn't recognise Comodo as a Certificate Authority, and it can't verify the validity of your attached certificate. You need to look into the settings of your PDF reader to add the Comodo key, or use a CA that is recognised by them by default, if any.

Comment: added Adobe version

Comment: Sounds more like an Adobe support question than an IT Sec question.

Comment: no wonder information security makes little progress society-wise if questions like this get closed and thereby hinder knowledge exchange... The message probably is "*Signer's identity is unknown because it has not been inclujded in your list of trusted certificates and none of its parent certificates are trusted certificates*". I got this message with Adobe Reader XI (version `11.0.23`) for a PDF signed with d-trust's sign-me services. Updating to a `2023.` version resolved the issue (at least for d-trust "qualified"-level signatures).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Signer's identity is unknown because it has not been included in your [...]"

Apparently your PDF client is not happy about your certificate because it should have been included in your *something*. I suggest expanding the window in order to read the word which would follow "your", because that word will probably be a good clue about what your problem actually is.

If your PDF reading software is Adobe Reader, you may want to read [this page](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/certificate-signatures.html), and to consult the [Adobe Approved Trust List members](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/approved-trust-list1.html): these are the CA that Adobe recognizes as valid for issuing certificates to sign documents. I see no mention of "Comodo" in that list, which can go a long way towards explaining your problem. However, Sectigo is in the list which was formerly know as Comodo.

Comment: signature validity is unknown because it has not been included in your list of trusted certificates and none of its parent certificates are trusted certificates

Comment: but I can't add to list of trusted certificates, because it's in my personal certificate